# Getting a periodic error in azure System.Net.Sockets.SocketException

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, azure, elmah

I am using Elmah to log errors on my web app hosted in azure. the web app is written in c# mvc4. 
Periodically getting this error (some days more than others) and don't understand how it could happen.

```
System.Net.Sockets.SocketExceptionNo such host is known

System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005): No such host is known
   at System.Net.Dns.InternalGetHostByName(String hostName, Boolean includeIPv6)
   at System.Net.Dns.GetHostAddresses(String hostNameOrAddress)
   at System.Net.Sockets.UdpClient.Connect(String hostname, Int32 port)
   at PixtrWebApi.Controllers.SessionsController.Counter(String key, Int32 value)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClassf.<GetExecutor>b__9(Object instance, Object[] methodParameters)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.Execute(Object instance, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpers.RunSynchronously[TResult](Func`1 func, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

The app uses a hard coded url for a db which is also hosted in azure. Think it might be an azure problem but not sure. Any ideas how to debug this?

Comment: Did you find any information about this?

Comment: left azure...to many bugs